# Custom Listview - multiselect items and colour

Tags: android, listview

I am using custom ListView adapter, and its working well.

I am currently using a checkBox to stored the checked values, but I think it might be better to change the background colour of the list item when it is selected.

I have tried (and failed) to do this using selectors, and I tried to modify my code to change the View background.

Here is my Custom adapter code, can this be change to set a blue background when a row is selected, and maintain the selection if multiple are selected?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> images;
    ArrayList folderName;
    boolean[] checkBoxState;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images, ArrayList folderName){

        this.context = c;
        this.images = images;
        this.folderName = folderName;
        this.context = context;
        checkBoxState=new boolean[images.size()];

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView iconImage;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }


    public void performClick(Integer position) {

        if(isChecked(position))
        {
            checkBoxState[position] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            checkBoxState[position] = true;

        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectedAll(ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions) {
        for(int i = 0; i< checkedPositions.size(); i++){
            checkBoxState[checkedPositions.get(i)] = true;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deselectedAll(ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions) {
        for(int i = 0; i< checkedPositions.size(); i++){
            checkBoxState[checkedPositions.get(i)] = false;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean isChecked(Integer pos){
        if(checkBoxState[pos] == true)
    return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //View gridView;
        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filename);
             holder.iconImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

            holder.title.setText(folderName.get(position).toString());


        holder.iconImage.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

        //Set the state of the
        //CheckBox using the boolean array
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);


        //for managing the state of the boolean
        //array according to the state of the
        //CheckBox

        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
                {
                    checkBoxState[position]=true;

                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxState[position]=false;
                }

            }

        });

            return v;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have the state of the checkboxes working for multiple selection, great!

Why not use this method to do the background colour too?

Find this line in your code (your adapter)

```
    //Set the state of the
    //CheckBox using the boolean array
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
```

and put this underneath

```
v.setBackgroundColor( (checkBoxState[position]) ? Color.parseColor("#0000FF") : Color.parseColor("#000000") );
```

Change the colours to match your needs but basically the first colour is the SELECTED colour you wish, whereas the second colour is the colour when the item is NOT selected.

Enjoy!

Comment: No problem - nice to see the view holders being used also! ;)